# Implementing simple authentication on a TCP Server from NodeJS

Tags: sockets, authentication, node.js, tcp

I am almost sure I don't understand the basic concepts of a TCP server and I'm not treating the data as streams, and worse than that, I might not be using the events very well.

I wanted the tcp server to write to the socket 'username: ' so you can then type in your username (on a tcp client like netcat or telnet), and then the tcp server must treat that next data as a username. So far it does work (although I'm almost sure there are better ways to do this), and next it should write 'password: ' so you could type in your password, and if it's the right one, it should then validate the credentials and do more stuff... But what happens is that when you type in the password, it writes again 'password: ' because the `socket.write('password: ');` is itself inside another `socket.on('data',function(){//etc});`

Here's the code I have so far:

```
var net = require('net');

var server = net.createServer(function (socket) {
    socket.addListener("connect", function () {
        socket.write('username: ');
        socket.on('data',function(data){
            var username = data.toString().replace('\n','');
            socket.write('password: ');
            socket.on('data',function(data){
                var password = data.toString().replace('\n','');
                // verify authentication here
                // Do more stuff
            });
        });
    });
});

server.listen('8000','localhost');
```

What is the correct way to implement this ? I'm only implementing this because I need to receive uploads (streams) that may not have an ending and don't come all at once. Am I being really stupid by trying to solve this problem with a TCP server ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just a quick answer: try .once or .one instead of on, that should only trigger each callback once. The given answer is also correct and a more complete solution.

Answer (score 2):

you can use node [ftp server](https://github.com/billywhizz/nodeftpd) source for a reference.

Main problem in your code: stream 'data' event gives you incoming data split into chunks. For example, if client issued two write('username: u\n') and write('password: p\n') you could expect data content to be anything from 'username: u\npassword: p\n' to 25 'data' events with 'u', 's', 'e', 'r' etc data buffers. You need to buffer incoming chunks or use state machine.